# Excel color scale based on alphabetical order

Tags: excel, colors

I like Excel's color scale feature in the Conditional Formatting menu and I am trying to get it to work for text values.

The way it works for numerical values is that it color-codes the lowest and highest values each with a certain color and then any values in between form a gradient between the min and max colors.

I'd like to be able to do this with text based on the alphabetical order. So let's say I have a table of:

```
AT  ANY BOY CAT
BAT CAT DAD AT
```

"ANY" would be the lowest value and "DAD" is the highest. I've applied the color scale to the table but none of the cells get colored. It seems like the values need to be numerical for a color scale to work. Is there a way to make this work? I'd rather not dive into any VB macros.

Using Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

JNevill's answer applies to a single letter but the same CODE function can be used multiple times with functions like MID or RIGHT to get unique numbers for each text value.

For example, if two text values are "Apple" and "Allure" in cells A3 and B3 you could use the following formulas:

=CODE(a3)
will get you 65

=CODE(b3)
will also get you 65 since you're asking for the ASCII of letter A both times so this won't work

---

=CODE(mid(a3,2,1))
will get you 112 since you're asking for the ASCII of the second letter ("P")

=CODE(mid(b3,2,1))
will get you 108 since you're asking for the ASCII of the second letter ("L") so this would work

You can concatenate the values of the first and second letters to get a longer, unique value:
=CODE(a3) & CODE(MID(a3,2,1))
will get you 65112

=CODE(b3) & CODE(MID(b3,2,1))
will get you 65108

---

Use however many combinations of the MID and RIGHT functions with CODE to get unique values that you can then apply color scales to.

NOTE: You'll have to convert any concatenated string into a number, so you can wrap the whole formula in =VALUE( xxxx ) and use the colour scales on that.

Be thoughtful of how complex the combinations need to be based on your text data set, because in the example of Apple and Allure, a combination of the first letters and last letters (you can get the last letters using the RIGHT function) would both be looking at A's and E's and therefore return the same number.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit of a workaround and not exactly what you are looking for, but in the next column (or row) you could use `=Code(A1)`... `=Code(A2)`... etc

This will get the ASCII character number for the character in each cell, which is a number. Then you could apply your conditional formatting to that.

[image]

Comment: That's a good thought. Unfortunately my real application uses more than single letters so the CODE function doesn't work. Updated the original example to show this.